# Displaying postcode on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the number of guests who have stayed into each of the hotels (three hotels in total). My code is below.

```
select hotelbook.hotelname, postcode, count(guestid)
from hotel, hotelbook
group by hotelname
```

I have to display the number of guests, which I have done successfully. I have to also display the name of the hotel, which I've done. And I also have to display the postcode, which is the problem for me at the moment. When I run this code, everything looks fine, but the postcode for the three hotels is the same.

I looked back at my created table, but I've given unique postcodes to the three hotels. Help is, as ever, appreciated.

EDIT - code has been changed to:

```
select hotel.hotelname, postcode, count(guestid)
from hotel, hotelbooking
group by hotelname
```

Post codes are unique for every hotel, thanks for the help. However, the count is the same for each hotel. Help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does it help if you include postcode to the GROUP BY? `group by hotelname, postcode`. By the way, is better to do an explicit JOIN between the two tables instead of an impolitic one using the ',' in between.

Comment: Do the tables relate in some way?

Comment: @JörgMäder I added postcode in the group by section of the code, which didn't do much unfortunately. Now, using that code, it gives me hotelnumber 1 three times with different post codes for each.

Comment: @Strawberry Hotel contains hotel name and postcode, while hotelbooking contains guestid and hotel name.

Comment: You currently has a cross join. So this is bringing back every combination of hotel and hotelbook. As the postcode is not specified in the GROUP BY clause the one it will bring back can be from any of the rows that contribute to the count of each guestid. This is why you need to use a solution like that proposed below by @JörgMäder

Comment: @Kickstart I changed the code :) Check below in the answer. I changed it to:

select hotel.hotelname, postcode, count(guestid)
from hotel, hotelbooking
group by hotelname

Comment: And that gave me unique post codes but now, the count is the same for each one, which is the problem. Any help? @Kickstart

Comment: You still need to specify the columns that you are joining on. You code at the moment is linking ever single booking to every single hotel (in the code by @JörgMäder this is done with the OUTER JOIN and  ON hotel.hotelname = hotelbook.hotelname). It is also best practice to have all the non aggregate columns from the SELECT statement in the GROUP BY (ie, add the postcode as well)

Answer (score 1):

Following your example, I assume the the column `hotelname` appears in both tables and can be used for the relation (see comment below)

```
select hotel.hotelname, postcode, count(guestid) as cnt
from hotel OUTER JOIN hotelbook ON hotel.hotelname = hotelbook.hotelname
group by hotel.hotelname, postcode
```

By the way, it's better to use a 'non-speaking' primary key to connect between tables. That means add a column `hotelid` (mostly a incrementing number) to table `hotel` (and use it as primary key), and use this key in all other tables as foreign key to refer to the hotel `table`.

Comment: "non-speaking"? what's that?

Comment: I tried that but I'm still getting an error - this is my current code, sir:

select hotelbooking.hotelname, postcode, count(guestid)
from hotel, hotelbooking
group by hotelname

Comment: @Strawberry: Any hotel wants that their guest remember the hotel name. So this value has a sense outside the data base. Now assume, the hotel gets a new owner, and they wants to change the name of the hotel. In this case, you have to update every table, which uses this name (and don't forget one!) On the other side, if you give the hotel a internal id, which has no other sense than identify the hotel, no one is ever interested to change this id, even if the hotel gets a new name. 'Non-Speaking' id have a much longer lifetime than 'speaking' ones.

Comment: Sorry, thre were 2 typos in my solution, which are now corrected. Don't select `hotelname` from table `hotelbooks`, because it appears there more often than in table `hotel`. And in `group by hotelname` sql doesn't known from which table it should take `hotelname`. Use the fully qualified name `hotel.hotelname` to clarify that.

Comment: Ah ok, I changed my code to this now:

select hotel.hotelname, postcode, count(guestid)
from hotel, hotelbooking
group by hotelname

Which works, as it gives me different post codes, but the count is 10 for all of them. Hmm, I think that's about right. Will check now.

Comment: @JörgMäder My count is now 10 for every hotel - so 10 people checked into each one. I don't think this part is right but the post code has changed due to your advice in changing code.